# How can I hide a subset of shared records in a customer community?

Tags: customer-community, digital-experience

We are using a customer community.
We have a sharing set rule as follows:
Case    User:Account = Case:Account Read/Write

[image]

On the case object, we have a custom picklist field called: Audience (Internal/External)

The case contact can still be the customer user, as well as the customer account. So customer users still see both types of cases.

There is a request that Customer users will NOT have access to a case with: 'Internal' audience.

- I don't want to create a record type for this (although I am not sure it will matter)

Is there a way I can hide Internal Cases from Customer users ?

I am using the 'Customer Community Login' license type.

- Can I use sharing rules as suggested ? We have multiple customers, we can't create a public group for each.

Comment: which license type you areusing?  if it is customer community plus license   you can create  sharing rules  /  share using public groups also.

Comment: I am using the 'Customer community Login' license. How can I use a sharing rule on top of the sharing set ? Sharing is additive, isn't it ?

Comment: sharing rules are for plus license  , it will not work for customer community licence.   pleae refer this doc  for features provided for each license.  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

1. I created a new lookup field on the case called: Customer (Related list: Customer's cases)
2. Changes the sharing set from: user.account = case.account to:
   user.account = case.customer
3. added appropriate validation rules so internal cases can't have a customer associated.
4. updated the page layouts to show the new related list in the customer community.
5. The create flows update the new customer field accordingly.